# Vector space. Prove that...

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $(V,+,\dot\ )$ a real vector space. There are defined two operations on cartesian product $V^C=V\times V$:

[image]

How should be proven that:

[image]?

Thank you for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $z_1=\alpha_1+i\beta_1$ and $z_2=\alpha_2+i\beta_2$ then
$$z_1\cdot z_2=\alpha_1\alpha_2-\beta_1\beta_2+i(\alpha_1\beta_2+\beta_1\alpha_2)$$
Set $\alpha_1\alpha_2-\beta_1\beta_2=\gamma_1$ and $\alpha_1\beta_2+\beta_1\alpha_2=\gamma_2$
Therefore $$(z_1\cdot z_2)(x,y)=(\gamma_1+i\gamma_2)(x,y)=(\gamma_1x-\gamma_2y,\gamma_1y+\gamma_2x)$$
On the other hand 
$$z_2(x,y)=(\alpha_2+i\beta_2)(x,y)=(\alpha_2x-\beta_2y,\alpha_2y+\beta_2x)$$
With respect to $z_1$
$$z_1(\alpha_2x-\beta_2y,\alpha_2y+\beta_2x)=(\alpha_1+i\beta_1)(\alpha_2x-\beta_2y,\alpha_2y+\beta_2x)=(\alpha_1\alpha_2x-\alpha_2\beta_2y-\beta_1\alpha_2y-\beta_1\beta_2x,\alpha_1\alpha_2y+\alpha_1\beta_2x+\beta_1\alpha_2x-\beta_1\beta_2 y)=((\alpha_1\alpha_2-\beta_1\beta_2)x-(\alpha_1\beta_2+\beta_1\alpha_2)y,(\alpha_1\alpha_2-\beta_1\beta_2)y+(\alpha_1\beta_2+\beta_1\alpha_2)x)=(\gamma_1x-\gamma_2y,\gamma_1y+\gamma_2x)$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume $z_1,z_2$ are complex numbers and the dot means normal multiplication in $\mathbb{C}$.

In that case, try to think of what $z_2(x,y)=(\alpha_2+\beta_2 i)(x,y)$ actually looks like - you already have a formula for that. Now, take your resulting vector and multiply it with $z_1$, giving you $z_1\cdot (z_2\cdot(x,y))$.

Then, take $(z_1\cdot z_2)=(\alpha_1\alpha_2-\beta_1\beta_2 +i(\alpha_1\beta_2+\alpha_2\beta_1))$ and multiply that number with your vector $(x,y)$.

Compare the results - if they are the same, you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you write a member of $V^C$ as a column, the multiplication by a scalar can be defined as
$$(\alpha+i\beta)\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&-\beta\\\beta&\alpha\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$$

But the 2x2 matrix is exactly the [matrix representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers) of the number $\alpha+i\beta$. So the multiplication of such matrices corresponds to the multiplication of complex numbers and that's exactly what you want.